# Estilo en paginacion de codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en la que tiene que mostrar un cierto contenido en forma de post, esto lo hace muy bien, la cuestion es al momento de mostrar la paginacion, ya que no e logrado aplicar de forma correcta los estilos de la plantilla que estoy utilizando.

Estos son los estilos de la paginacion de la plantilla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es su respectivo codigo.

```
<nav>
     <ul class="pagination">
           <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
           <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
           <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
           <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

El problema que se me presenta es este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El html auto generado por codeignater es.

```
<nav>
     <ul class="pagination">
         <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
         <li class="page-item page-link"><a href="http://localhost:700/plataforma_viejo_portal/welcome/index/7" data-ci-pagination-page="2">2</a></li>
         <li class="page-item page-link"><a href="http://localhost:700/portal/welcome/index/7" data-ci-pagination-page="2" rel="next">»</a></li>
    </ul>
```

He probado de todo en la parte de las configuración de la paginacion del codeigniter pero aun asi no logro dar con el cumplimiento de los estilos, esto es lo que tengo del lado de la configuracion.

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('welcome/index');
    $config['total_rows'] = count($this->Post->getListPostGen());
    $config['per_page'] = 7;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['num_links'] = 5;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;

    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item page-link">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';

    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page-link"> ';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';

    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item page-link">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item page-link">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item page-link">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

Amigos lo que trato de hacer es que en el html generado por codeigniter en la etiqueta a se agrege este estilo `page-link` pero no e podido dar con la forma correcta, alguien podria el ayudar a dar solución, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir atributos ('class', 'id', 'rel', etc...) a los enlaces mediante la variable *$config['attributes']*:

```
$config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'page-link');
```